# How can I get the path of an object in a JavaScript heap snapshot in devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, snapshot

I see yellow backgrounds on some objects, but how can I get the path to those objects to help me further in debugging?

For example, I see

[image]

and I'm interested in the EventEmitter. When I click on an EventEmitter and look in the "Retainers" panel, I see

[image]

How can I see what the path to the object is?